# I try to web scrap IBDM data with selenium and got an error of the following

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Following things happened when I'm doing web scraping. Please assist me.

> WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
> (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to
> DevTools)

I tried this `xpath` to get web elements but I got an error.

> driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="lister-item-index unbold
> text-primary"]')

Comment: Could we please get a [mcve]?